# Display ipaddress using qt on Raspberry Pi

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, ip-address

I am trying to display the Ip address of a Raspberry Pi in a QTextEdit box;

```
IPAddress = new QTextEdit("Current IP Address: \n", this);
QString tem = QString::number(system("hostname -I"));
IPAddress->append(tem);
IPAddress->setStyleSheet("QTextEdit{border: none;outline:none;border-image: none;}");
IPAddress->show();
```

The Problem is this displays the IP Address as 0.

How do I get this to display the actual IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a "problem", because:

```
QString::number(system("hostname -I"));
```

returns "0" (most likely because `system("hostname -I")` command result is 0), so the `QTextEdit` displays `0`.

Note that when you run a process:

- It returns an exit code (`main` function returned value) as integer. In mostly all cases 0 means it succeeded, anything else means it fails.
- It displays some information to standard output (what's sent to `std::cout`).

So, when you call `system("hostname -I"))` it returns 0 if successfull and then you need to parse its standard output to find the IP address that was printed here.

You can catch the call's standard output by using `QProcess` or by redirecting it to a file and then reading the file (`system("hostname -I > ip.txt")`may work, to be tested)

Or, to get your IP address as text, the best is to use [QNetworkInterface](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html), check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835989/get-local-ip-address-in-qt), then you can display it in your QTextEdit.

Comment: I am going to note that that I am doing this on a Raspberry Pi and on the terminal this command does display the ipaddress, but i may be misunderstanding something

Comment: You're mixing program result and output. See my edited post.

Comment: I am attempting to use the QNetwork Interface as shown in that post, however getting fairly constant build errors declaring that QHostAddress is undefined, i.e undefined reference to 'QHostAddress::~QHostAddress()'

Comment: Got it working forgot to add QT += network to pro file

Answer (score 2):

Using `system()` is ugly and, unless you're coding a throwaway project, you should consider using [`QNetworkInterface`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html) class to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 for (QHostAddress address: QNetworkInterface::allAddresses())
    if (address.protocol() == QAbstractSocket::IPv4Protocol)
       IPAddress->append(address.toString());
```